# output of permutation code (block by block) - VB6 coding

Tags: vb6, permutation

In basic, I have this code:

```
ReDim aPos(1 To Len(sInput))

Do
    aPos(1) = aPos(1) + 1
    For X = 1 To Len(sInput) - 1 
        If aPos(X) > Len(sInput) Then 
            aPos(X) = 1 
            aPos(X + 1) = aPos(X + 1) + 1
        End If
    Next X
    If aPos(Len(sInput)) > Len(sInput) Then Exit Do
```

the only thing I don't understand is what the check is at the end, last line. It looks to me like it's checking if there were more indexes found from the "Position" array that was temporarily created than those that came from the input array. Is that right? What I'm not following is the math here, the iterative nature, if you will.

Comment: I don't understand what is being done, but the last line is comparing the value of the last element of the array to the length of what I am assuming is a string and if the value is greater than the length exiting the `Do` loop.

Comment: could you post more of the code? Show the declaration of the variables, and the content of sInput, and the true end of the do loop. Also please use Option Explicit at the top of your code to force variable declaration.

Answer (score 1):

below is a small test project to show the progress of your apos
i changed as little as possible from your code

you can see that in the end apos will be filled with '1' except the last element which will have the string length of sInput plus 1

```
'1 form with
'    1 command button : name=Command1
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim X As Integer
  Dim sInput As String
  Dim apos() As Integer
  Dim lngTime As Long
  sInput = "Hello"
  ReDim apos(1 To Len(sInput)) As Integer
  Do
    apos(1) = apos(1) + 1
    For X = 1 To Len(sInput) - 1
      If apos(X) > Len(sInput) Then
        apos(X) = 1
        apos(X + 1) = apos(X + 1) + 1
        ShowApos apos
        lngTime = GetTickCount + 100
        Do Until GetTickCount > lngTime
          DoEvents
        Loop
      End If
    Next X
    If apos(Len(sInput)) > Len(sInput) Then Exit Do
  Loop
End Sub

Private Sub ShowApos(apos() As Integer)
  Dim intIndex As Integer
  Dim strShow As String
  For intIndex = LBound(apos) To UBound(apos)
    strShow = strShow & CStr(apos(intIndex)) & " "
  Next intIndex
  Caption = strShow
End Sub
```

so all it does is have some counter which fills up to len(sInput)+1 and set all the other elements of the array to 1

the last line will make sure you step out of the loop when you reach the final value

Comment: thanks!  I forgot about this but that is an answer I can use.